# Unity objects does not completely touch on each other

Tags: unity-game-engine

in unity I have 2 boxes, one is player other is floor. floor has box collider and player has box collider and rigitbody2d. Game is supposed to be side-scrolling. but player does not collide (or touch) with floor perfectly. player has to stay at x=any y= 0.32 for touching floor perfectly. but player can only stay at -0.30. player look like it is flying.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to play with player rigidbody, in case its wrongly configured (using default) and colliders (they are default box collider 2d). I checked settings in case default settings not set correctly. it might be because the sizes are too small I am not sure.

Comment: Can we see the collider shape of your floor? And can you please embed the images in your question rather than using links

Comment: well I tried embed but it linked instead.. wait I will try

Comment: I cant due to my rep level, I can only link them.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your collision detection is not interpolating between physics steps, so it will be stopping just before or just after a collision. You need to set [Rigidbody.interpolation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyInterpolation.html) to either  Interpolate or Extrapolate. I would reccoment Interpolate, but try both and pick which one you prefer.

Comment: You can also try setting collision mode to `CollisionDetectionMode.ContinuousDynamic`

Comment: collision detection is already set to continous and I did try to set Rigidbody.interpolation to Interpolate and Extrapolate  but result is same.

Comment: Continous and ContinousDynamic are not the same , but your issue is likley something else if the interpolation mode didn't fix it